# "Между тем" происходит от слова "тот" или "тема"?

Tags: этимология, грамматика

Если от "тот", то почему не "между теми"?
Потому что "тем" творительный падеж, единственное число, средний род?

Answer (score 1):

В словаре указаны следующие сочетания с предлогом "между":

1) **Между прочим.** 1. в зн. нареч.  Говорить м. прочим. М. прочим обратить внимание на что-л. -2. в зн. вводн. словосоч. **К слову сказать**.

2) **Между тем,** в зн. нареч. В то **время**, тем временем. М. тем наступил вечер.

3) **А между тем, в зн. союза.** Тем временем, в то же **время**. Между тем как, в зн. союза. Употр. при сопоставлении двух явлений, событий, происходящих **одновременно**.

4) **Между делом,** в зн. нареч. Мимоходом, попутно.

Из этого можно сделать **вывод**,  что "между тем" относится (1) или  ко временной тематике (**между тем  и этим временем**, обозначение промежутка времени), (2) или имеет значение сопоставления и несоответствия  одновременных событий (из одного промежутка времени). **Отсюда и следует форма указательного местоимения "тем" (ед.ч. Т.п.).**

**Примеры**

(1) **Между тем** наступил вечер, и в небо вышла полная, в соку и силе, луна. [В. А. Солоухин. Капля росы (1959)]

(2)  Настоящая зима стояла в городе вот уже неделю, **а между тем** только кончался ноябрь.

Answer (score 0):

"Теми" - это творительный падеж *множественного* числа, откуда бы ему здесь взяться?

"Между тем"  происходит от слова "то" - т. е.  "тот", только среднего рода. 
"То", "это" и "что" используется как обобщенное название или местоимения для всего неназываемого, независимо от рода, и даже для *того*, что грамматического рода вообще не иметь не может: *"**Это** вы знаете", "**То**, **что** вы знаете, **это** хорошо" и т. п.* Все эти слова: *"то", "это"* и *"что"* - сами по себе согласуются со средним родом **единственного** числа, в этом значении множественного иметь не могут (хотя близкое к ним "кто" требует мужского рода, но изредка допускает и род женский, и число множественное).

Вас, видимо, спутало соображение, что предлог "между" якобы обязательно требует множественного числа. Это не так. В этом выражении сохранилось историческое управление. Сравните: *между делом (не "делами"), между прочим*.

Answer (score 0):

Происходит от "то" в собирательном значении (всё то), допускающем смысловую множественность, разделимость (то да это уже упомянутое).